# Last class is not setting on last category in Array

Tags: magento-1.9, if

We have an If statement which sets a class name to categories in the array, The first category has the class of "first" and the last category has the class of "last" however the Last class name is not being set and i assume it is because it doesn't think it is the end of our array and i don't understand why

this is the code

```
$store_categories = $this->getLeftCategories();
if ($count = count($store_categories)) {

$block_title = $this->getBlockTitle();
if ( empty($block_title) ) $block_title = 'Categories';
?>
<div class="block block-left-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($block_title1) ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul id="left-nav">
        <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach ($store_categories as $_category) {
            $class = array();        
   if (!$i) {
                $class[] = 'first';
            } 
            if($i == $count) {          
                $class[] = 'last';
            }

            echo $this->drawOpenCategoryItem($_category, 0, $class);

            $i++;
        } ?>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div
```

If anyone can see the reason it isn't setting the Last class or if i have wrote the IF statement wrong could you let me know as i have been looking at this for hours and cant see anything

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with `if(($i + 1) == $count) { ...` because for an array with 3 items you will have i = 0, 1, 2 or move `$i++;` above `if($i == $count) {`.